# How to write a macro to generate list item

Tags: specman

I have a list of structs, the struct has a field which defines it's type (assume it's name).
I would to have a macro as follows:

```
MYKEEP <name>.<field> <ANY KEEP>;
```

which would be translated to:

```
keep value(mylist.has(it.name == <name>)) => mylist.first(it.name == <name>).<field> <ANY KEEP>
```

Is it possible to do it without an "as computed" macro?

Comment: Don't really get what you're constraining here. `mylist.has(it.name == <name>)` would return a boolean value, for which you can't dereference any `<field>`.

Comment: Sorry a typo, meant to write first and not has

Comment: So basically you want to know if you can simplify the constraint, right?

Comment: Also, what you showed is not a `define as computed` macro, but a regular `define as` one.

Comment: As i said, i don't want it to be as computed

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you want to get a list of structs as an input, check the value of some of the 
struct's fields, and then assign a constant value to a different struct field
according to that value.

taking performance into account,this  kind of 'Injective' relationship between the two fields should
be in proceedural code rather than generative.  (most likely in post_generate()).

consider using a define as macro that looks like this:

```
 define <name_induced_field'struct_member>  "MYKEEP <name'exp> <field'exp> <ANY_KEEP'exp>" as{

post_generate() is also{
    for each in l{
        if (it.t==<name'exp>){
            it.<field'exp> = <ANY_KEEP'exp>;
        };
    };

};
};
```

and then use it in the code like so:

```
type mytype: [AA,BB];

struct s {

t:mytype;
!i:int;

};

extend sys{

MYKEEP AA i 1;
MYKEEP BB i 2;

l:list of s;
keep l.size()==5;
};
```

note: if the struct field has the same relationship to it's name in other cases ,consider
maybe constraining the field from within the struct, for example:

```
 define <name_induced_field'struct_member>  "MYKEEP <name'exp> <field'exp> <ANY_KEEP'exp>" as{
keep value(t==<name'exp>) => (<field'exp>==<ANY_KEEP'exp>);
};

type mytype: [AA,BB];

struct s {

MYKEEP AA i 1;
MYKEEP BB i 2;

t:mytype;
i:int;

post_generate() is also{
print me;
};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

proceedural code doesn't help me, because these fields may effect others in generation time.
I manged to find a macro that seems to work:

```
define <ana_packet_gen_con_keep1'exp>   "KEEP_CON [(<WORD>soft) ]<type'exp>\.<field'any> <exp>" as {
    keep for each (con) in it.containers {
        <WORD> (con.con_type==<type'exp>) => con.as_a(<type'exp>'con_type ana_container).<field'any> <exp>;
    };
};
```

Does having several "keep for each" effect the performance too much?

Comment: Isn't this slightly different than what you wanted in the question? This doesn't constrain your list to have an item of type `<type>`, or? Also, it constrains all items of type <type>, not just the first one.

Comment: It doesn't matter, this constraint is more "generic" i can modify it to receive the "struct" number.

Comment: No idea about the `for each`, but IMO, the solver anyway has to loop over all elements of a list to solve them. I would think that the limiting factor would be the size of your list, not the number of `for each` constraints you have.